# Customizing sqlalchemy create table DDL for alembic+snowflake

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic, snowflake-connector

I'm using sqlalchemy declarative models to create my snowflake schema, but since sqlalchemy generates ddl using lower-case identifiers, and snowflake uses upper-case identifiers, alembic can never conclude that a table already exists in snowflake (i.e. "I looked for my_schema.my_table but only found MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE").

Is there an event I can use to customize schema/table/column names in DDL and just upper-case them? It seems like this is a gap in the list of sqlalchemy events.